# Sympy Piecewise expression for even and odd numbers

Tags: sympy, floor, piecewise

The objective is to implement a Piecewise expression that gives 0 when n is even, and 1 when n is odd. One way to do it is using the floor function like below:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import n

f = Lambda((n,), Piecewise((0, Eq(n, floor(n / S(2)))),
                           (1, Eq(n, floor(n / S(2))+1))))

print(f(0))
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
```

However, this returns the wrong output:

```
0
1
1
Piecewise()
```

The correct output should be:

```
0
1
0
1
```

Another way to achieve the same is to use:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import n

f = Lambda((n,), Piecewise((0, Eq((-1)**n, 1)),
                           (1, Eq((-1)**n, -1))))

print(f(0))
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
```

and this returns the correct output. Is there a way to achieve this using the floor function in the original code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way would be to use `Mod`, like

```
Piecewise((0, Eq(Mod(n, 2), 0)), (1, Eq(Mod(n, 2), 1)))
```

However, since your function coincides exactly with the definition of `Mod`, you can just use it directly

```
Mod(n, 2)
```

or equivalently

```
n % 2
```